# Flash cue points: Link from a website to specific point in a flash animation

Tags: html, url, flash, hyperlink, cue-points

Well the title basically said it all.
I want to be able to link to a cue point in a flash animation

I've searched and searched in Google but all I can see was linking from flash to a website based on a que point.
The idea is this:
I create an animation in flash that contains multiple languages.
I want to create multiple links on my website. The user clickes a link in their language and opens the movie at the right "cue" point where his/her language shows.

I think this can be done with cue points but I'm not really the flash-expert to know how this works.
Hope that somebody else can provide me with some solid information!

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using variables in the link addresses. This means just add something like `?lang=eng` at the end of your linked URL. Flash can read that address (only from HTML embed) and have code that does something depending on what comes after the `lang=` part.

There's better ways to do this including real variable parsing but I just went with a simple converting browser address to String and then extract the last (language) bit. Just to see if that works too.

**For testing only** you need an MC and two textfields on stage with these instance names:

- `txt_url` shows the full browser address
- `txt_lang` shows the final 3 letter language code
- `MC_lang` is (your) movieclip that changes frames according to `txt_lang`

**customising**: you can customise your variable with these two lines:

> `var Index_one:int = 5 + int( tempSTR.indexOf("lang=") );`
>   Here `5` is because `lang=` has five characters. When you change the word you must change the number to match word/symbols length also.
>  `case "eng"` must match the language code you choose (eg: if you go with `?lang=english_UK` then in code it becomes `case "english_UK"`

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;


var str_url :String = "";

get_Language();


function get_Language () : void
{
    // GET LANGUAGE
    var url:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
    if (url != null) //if is not null 
    { txt_url.text = url; txt_lang.text = get_lang_URL(url); }

    //SET BY LANGUAGE
    if (txt_lang.length > 0) //if is not null 
    { 
        switch(txt_lang.text)
        {

            case "eng": MC_lang.gotoAndStop(1); break;
            case "jap": MC_lang.gotoAndStop(2); break;
            case "bra": MC_lang.gotoAndStop(3); break;
        }

    }

}

//EXTRACT LANGUAGE VARIABLE FROM ADDRESS
function get_lang_URL (input_str:String):String
{
    var tempSTR:String = input_str;
    var finalSTR:String = "";

    var Index_one:int = 5 + int( tempSTR.indexOf("lang=") );
    var Index_two = input_str.length - Index_one;

    finalSTR = tempSTR.substr(Index_one, Index_two );
    return finalSTR;
}
```